# WPF AutocompleteBox Multibinding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, multibinding

I am having problems multibinding WPF AutoCompleteBox.  I am multibinding to FirstNameTextBox and LastNameTextBox Text properties as shown and to the MainWindow.  In my converter, I am trying to access the AutoCompleteBox.Text which is always returning Nothing.  I tried SelectedItem as well, and is returning nothing and not the text typed by user.  Any suggestions? Thanks

```
<my1:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" FilterMode="StartsWith" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="CompanySearchTBox_TextChanged" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="companyNameTBox" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="119,0,1,0">
        <my1:AutoCompleteBox.Text>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiTextBoxConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
              <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding ElementName="firstNameTBox" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="lastNameTBox" Path="Text" />
                <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
              </MultiBinding.Bindings>                            
           </MultiBinding>
        </my1:AutoCompleteBox.Text>
</my1:AutoCompleteBox>
```

**In my converter**
I get the reference to MainWindow from the parameters and try to get the AutoCompleteBox.Text which is always returning Nothing. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
 mainWindow = CType(values.ElementAt(2), MainWindow)
 _logicalName = mainWindow.companyNameTBox.Text
```

**Updated MultiTextBoxConverter.Convert**

```
Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type,        ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Dim firstname = values.ElementAt(0).ToString
        Dim lastname = values.ElementAt(1).ToString
        Dim mainWindow As MainWindow, _logicalName As String = Nothing
        Dim clientInfo As Jewellery.ClientInfo = Nothing          

        If Not TryCast(values.ElementAt(2), MainWindow) Is Nothing Then
            mainWindow = CType(values.ElementAt(2), MainWindow)
            clientInfo = CType(mainWindow.FormGrid.DataContext, Jewellery.ClientInfo)
            If Not clientInfo Is Nothing Then
                If mainWindow.IsChecked = True Then
                    _logicalName = firstname + " " + lastname
                Else
                    _logicalName = mainWindow.companyNameTBox.Text

                End If

            End If
            If Not clientInfo Is Nothing Then clientInfo.Company.CompanyName = _logicalName
        End If
        Return _logicalName
    End Function
 Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Dim obj(3) As Object
        obj(0) = Binding.DoNothing
        obj(1) = Binding.DoNothing
        obj(2) = Binding.DoNothing
        Return obj
    End Function
```

Basically it is testing if a checkbox is checked and if true then return _logicalName = FirstName + " " + LastName else return AutoCompleteBox.Text

**Solution**

```
 Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Dim obj(3) As Object
        obj(0) = Binding.DoNothing
        obj(1) = Binding.DoNothing
        ****obj(2) = Binding.SourceUpdatedEvent****
        Return obj
    End Function
<!-- Added this as 3rd parameter to Multibinding code above -->
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="Text" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need further information to provide any help. You say: "In my converter". Do mean the multiTextBoxConverter.Convert method or the convertBack method?

Comment: Yes the MultiTextBoxConverter.Convert method all right.

Comment: The convert method will be called when either the firstnNameTBox.Text, lastNameTBox.Text or MainWindows.DataContext change in value. If this happens before anything else the autocompletebox.text is Nothing. I assume this is not the problem?!

Comment: I suppose you are right because if I replace the ACB with a normal TextBox, it works perfectly fine. Let me just update my Convert method above for you to have a look.

Comment: The problem is that every time I am typing something in the ACB, the Convert method gets Nothing for ACB.Text

Comment: Few things that confuse me(1)When you type smth. into the ABC, wpf will call ConvertBack-method not the Convert method. Convert is for converting "towards" the ABC.Text property and setting ABC.Text. ConvertBack is for updating the other textboxes, when ABC.Text is changed by the user(2)The intent behind _logicalName=mainWindow.companyNameTBox.Text seems to be to not change the value of ABC.Text. You can return Binding.DoNothing, which would be the more standard way to achieve this(3)If "Not clientInfo Is Nothing" is never true, ABC.Text will be set to Nothing, which can explain your behavior

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  Updated my ConvertBack method in initial post.  1) This is what I want to do, ie, converting something to ACB.Text because I want to set its Text property to the _logicalName which is calcualted.  I dont really care about changing other textboxes on ConvertBack coz I dont need it.  2)No, I am getting the ACB.Text from the window that user typed 3) I am using debugger and this is only for initial window loading when ClientInfo = nothing otherwise it never gets here once window has finished loading. Code works perfect with TextBox but not with the AutoCompleteBox

Comment: If I remove the multibinding part from xaml, the ACB gets the text set by user correctly.  Is there a problem with the multibinding there in the case with ACB?

Comment: I think, I cannot help you with this. When it works with a TextBox, it seems to be smth. about the ABC. Unfortunately, I do not know that much about ABCs. Sorry. Just one additional remark. Converters are usually used for conversion of values and no other logic. You are using your converter for making decisions, updating objects and other complex logic. It is not related to your problem, but in general it is easier to maintain your application, when you place your logic in Controls and Behaviors and not in Converters. Have a nice evening.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  No real complex logic there, just calculating _logicalName based on the inputs.

Comment: What I mean with complex logic: MultiValueConvert.Convert should take the values from values array and convert it to one resutling value. You, on the othe hand, are using the mainwindow to access the property you want to update by the converter, which makes not much sense to me, you are setting the property of clientInfo.Company.CompanyName which is not related to the binding in any way, and you are making the conversion result dependend on the state of some checkbox. None of this should be done in a converter in my opinion. Ideal: return firstname + " " + lastname and nothing else.

Comment: yes we had a long discussion about it here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f539efa-96b8-43d3-9f0b-dc47808927fe/bind-to-source-and-target-simultaneously?forum=wpf and just an adopted solution for the somewhat "complex" situation.  Would be ideal just returning like you mentioned.  Will try to update it without accessing the MainWindow's properties hopefully but even if you dont use this 'complex' logic of accessing those properties, how do you get the ACB to multibind?  How do you pass the text property from the ACB in the multibinding from xaml? I working on this ...

Comment: found it mate phewwwwwww!!! You were right, Something fishy was happening in the ConvertBack method. I updated the code above. Maybe you could have an explanation about it?